# Best practices to store user information in Redis

Tags: redis

I'm building a simple web application where I need to store user information when logged in.

The information that I need to store is in `json` format like:

`User:{'name': 'John', roles:[1,2,3]}`

I was thinking in storing the information with a combination of user + {user_id} like:

`User_1: {'name': 'John', roles=[1,2,3]}`

I needed to know if this is a good practice (thinking in retrieving the information fast) or if there is another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:**

Using `key: value` pair.

```
"User_1": "name: John, roles=[1,2,3]"
```

**Time complexity:** `O(1)`.

[x] But after getting the data from Redis you have to parse it again.

**Option 2:**

Using separate keys for `name` and `roles`.

```
"User_1_name": "John", 
"User_1_roles": [1,2,3]
```

**Time complexity:** `O(1)` per request. In total for your example case it's constant.

[x] Extra call for same user.

**Option 3:**

Using hash.

```
user_1: {
    "name": "John", 
    "roles": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

**Time complexity:** `O(N)`. Where `N` is the number of fields in hash. But for your example case it's constant.

In my opinion using a hash will be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is about the key, not value.

It's good practice to save user with `user+id` key.
And if you have another identify attribute for your user(Email for example), you'll need to map all users to their email.

So each user will have these keys in Redis:

`User_1`: `{'name': 'John', roles:[1,2,3], 'email': 'blabla@test.com'}`

`User_blabla@test.com_id`: `1`

When you needed to find user by email, you can get the user id by reading the `User_blabla@test.com_id`(which it's value is equal to user's id 1), then get the `User_1`.